# Find out if data from a for loop meets a certain criteria

Tags: java, variables, if-statement, for-loop, random

I'm trying to do is figure out how to see if data from a for loop meets a certain criteria. I want to use an if statement to do so (unless there's a better way), but the trouble I'm having is that the data is inside a for loop, and the code doesn't want me to use the values outside of that loop. Here is the code:

```
    //Create an array called schoolEnrollment of length numberOfStudents         
    Student[] myArray = new Student[numberOfStudents];  


    //Create enough objects of type Student to fill the array above
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfStudents; i++) {

        //Uses the instance of RandomNames to assign first and last names to each student
            //First names
            String[] firstNames1 = {"John", "Roxanne", "Dean", "Mary", "Shawn", "Sara",
                    "Peter", "Susie", "Jerry", "Juliet"};

            int idx = new Random().nextInt(firstNames1.length);
            String random = (firstNames1[idx]);

            String NextFirstName = random;

            //Last names
            String[] lastNames1 = {"Smith", "Brown", "Baker", "Doe", "Poe", "Allen", 
                    "Black", "Frederick", "Hunter", "Spencer"};

            int idx1 = new Random().nextInt(lastNames1.length);
            String random1 = (lastNames1[idx1]);

            String NextLastName = random1;


        //Randomly assign house locations to each student
        int houseLocation = (int) (0 + (Math.random() * (3 - 0)));
        //Randomly assign distance from school to each student
        int distanceFromSchool = (int) (0 + (Math.random() * (30 - 0)));;
        myArray[i] = new Student(NextFirstName, NextLastName, houseLocation, distanceFromSchool);

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfStudents; i++) {
        // display toString for each object
        System.out.println(myArray[i].toString());
    }

    //Create 4 other arrays of length numberOfStudents of type Student with the names
    //ridersOfNorthBus, ridersOfWestBus, ridersOfSouthBus, and ridersOfEastBus
    Student[] ridersOfNorthBus = new Student[numberOfStudents];

    Student[] ridersOfWestBus = new Student[numberOfStudents];

    Student[] ridersOfSouthBus = new Student[numberOfStudents];

    Student[] ridersOfEastBus = new Student[numberOfStudents];
```

So, what I'm trying to do is take the houseLocation (East, South, North, or West) that is randomly given by the for loop to see who would take which bus. Simply trying to use the houseLocation variable does not work because the program doesn't recognize the variable outside of the for loop. Also, creating another random instance of the variable wouldn't work because it probably wouldn't come up with the same values. I also can't put the code inside the for loop because then my arrays would all print out multiple times, which isn't what I want. Is there any way to do this? Thank you.

Also, not sure if it's needed, but here is the class that contains the houseLocation method:

```
public class Student {

//Create private instance variables with setters and getters
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private int houseLocation = 0;
private int distanceFromSchool = 0;


//Set values for private instance variable house location
public void north() {
    int North = 0;
    if (houseLocation == North)
        North = houseLocation;

}
public void west() {
    int West = 1;
    if (houseLocation == West)
        West = houseLocation;
}
public void south() {
    int South = 2;
    if (houseLocation == South)
        South = houseLocation;
}
public void east() {
    int East = 3;
    if (houseLocation == East)
        East = houseLocation;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be using the houseLocation variable for comparing since it's scope is only within the for loop.  Instead you should have a getter method for Student class to get the houseLocation for a particular instance.  Ex.

```
myArray[i].getHouseLocation(); //something like this to access the houseLocation for each element (Student) of the array...
```

You already set the house location for each student in your constructor just create or (use a getter you already have) to access the data.

Getter method in Student class:

```
public int getHouseLocation()
{
   return this.houseLocation;
}
```

Comment: That actually makes a lot of sense. Now I feel kind of stupid for not realizing that, but oh well. At least I got it done. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Haha!  Don't feel stupid sometimes we all make silly mistakes...I'm glad I was able to help!

Answer (score 1):

You have a `myArray` array declared before the for loop, which you populate with `Student` instances in the for loop:

```
myArray[i] = new Student(NextFirstName, NextLastName, houseLocation, distanceFromSchool);
```

One of the `Student` properties is the house location. Therefore you have all the data you need outside the for loop.

You can populate the ridersOfXBus arrays with this code :

```
Student[] ridersOfNorthBus = new Student[numberOfStudents];
Student[] ridersOfWestBus = new Student[numberOfStudents];
Student[] ridersOfSouthBus = new Student[numberOfStudents];
Student[] ridersOfEastBus = new Student[numberOfStudents];

int northCount=0;
int southCount=0; 
int westCount=0;
int eastCount=0;

for (Student student : myArray) {
    switch (student.getHouseLocation()) {
    case 0:
        ridersOfNorthBus[northCount]=student;
        northCount++;
        break;
    case 1:
        ridersOfWestBus[westCount]=student;
        westCount++;
        break;
    case 2:
        ridersOfSouthBus[southCount]=student;
        southCount++;
        break;
    case 3:
        ridersOfEastBus[eastCount]=student;
        eastCount++;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to fill the last four arrays depending on the house location.

You're right that you have the house locations in the first `for` loop.

But you also initialize each Student object with one of those house locations. In the Student constructor, you could save this value in a field in Student. You could expose the value of this field through a method in Student.

```
public class Student {
     ...
     public Student( String firstName, String lastName, 
                     int houseLocation, int distanceFromSchool ) 
     {
         ...
     }

     public int getHouseLocation() {
         return houseLocation;
     }
```

Then, as you iterate through the Student objects in `myArray`, you can simply call that Student method to get its house location, and use that to pick which of the location-based arrays gets the Student.

Answer (score 0):

At each iteration of your loop, you (already) create an instance of your `Student` class that captures the randomly-generated details of one student.  These are recorded in array `myArray`, which is declared outside the loop.  These objects contain the `houseLocation` information, and they may be accessed outside the loop, as indeed your code already demonstrates.  Get your house locations from them.

Answer (score 0):

You have to think about the scope of the variables you are declaring/using. If you declare something inside your for loop then it will only exist as long as the for loop is running. As soon as the for loop is finished all variables declared in the scope of the for loop are gone. 
I am not sure what it is you want to achieve exactly. If for instance your aim is to populate your 4 ridersOfXBus arrays. You could do the following. Declare the arrays together with your myArray (at the top of the for loop that is). That way the arrays will be visible within your for loop. When populating your students array (myArray) inside the for loop you can then easily populate the ridersArrays as well (directly in the for loop). So you can put each student that's created in two arrays (in myArray containg all the students, and according to the direction they are taking in one of the riders arrays).

Hope that helps. If not try clarifying your question.